# Two identical interfaces: Yet, can't cast one as the other?

Tags: java, interface

*I'm doing this as part of a Java tutorial, so it is probably not very hard to answer at all -- I am very stuck, though, so thanks for any help!*

I have the following problem: I have an interface a, and a library I downloaded as part of the tutorial which takes an (implemented) interface of type a and displays it in a GUI. The trouble is that it does not compile; eclipse says I must cast it. When I do, it compiles, but gives me a casting error.

The strange thing is that both interfaces have exactly the same code. In fact, I copied and pasted the library's one over mine, and it still does not work.

How can it be that the two interfaces have the same code but I can't cast? What is wrong with my implementation of the interface?

If you need any additional information, please tell me!

Comment: Is the interface part of the library? If it is, use the one in the library, don't create another interface with same package and name in your own project.

Comment: Why can't you use the original interface in the library? When you're rolling your own, are you using the same package name for your interface? If so, you can "eclipse" the original one. Otherwise you have two different interfaces that say the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot cast between two unrelated interfaces, no matter whether their definition is identical or not. The language simply does not allow that. Two distinct interface declarations, even if they are identical, result in two distinct interfaces.

You need to change your design so that you only have a single interface and all clients and implementers of the interface refer to the same single interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the key! I had written my own interface, whereas I should have imported the other one all along. Thanks for the fast, concise answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is one of them a standard interface? You should make one of them `extend` the other.

You should probably not create a second identical interface and instead just use the existing one in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Type Casting simply means converting one type of object reference to another type of object reference. source and the destination must be related by inheritance in order to do a up cast or a downcast. That means, Either classes should be related with sub class-super class relationship or a particular interface should extend an interface in order to cast into it.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30871&seqNum=5

Comment: Not well worded. It's typecasting, not 'object casting', and it doesn't mean that actually, it means *treating* one type as another type. No 'conversion'. Source and destination *types* must be related by inheritance or 'implements': for example, one can be a class and the other an interface implemented by the class.

Comment: Edited the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast interfaces if they are not directly related because it's breaking type guarantees java has.

However, if you still need a bridge between 2 interfaces you could do it the same way used for classed - create a wrapper class:

```
class CastUnrelatedIdenticalInterfaces {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FromInterface from = getExternalInterface();
        ToInterface to = new ToInterfaceWrapper(from);
    }

    private static FromInterface getExternalInterface() {
        return null;
    }
}

interface FromInterface {
    String[] apply(String[] args);
}

interface ToInterface {
    String[] apply(String[] args);
}

class ToInterfaceWrapper implements ToInterface {
    private FromInterface from;
    public ToInterfaceWrapper(FromInterface from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] apply(String[] args) {
        return from.apply(args);
    }
}
```